# Javascript Beautify option in sublime text 2 always disabled

Tags: javascript, sublimetext2

I have installed javascript beautifier by following this:
https://github.com/cancerhermit/Sublime-JS-Beautifier

Now when I right click in the javascript file, I see 'Javascript Beautify' option. But its always disabled. Will appreciate some help here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your code is already beautiful?

Comment: I have the opposite problem, now that it's installed I can't stop it from beautifying minimised js files :-/

Comment: @dfsq No, that's not the case..but your comment is funny :)

Comment: @geoidesic I have switched to sublime 3 and HTML-CSS-JS Prettify module, it works well for most cases. But messes up html at times, EJS to be specific. Which is a templating system in node.js

Comment: i got the same problem with sublime text 3

Comment: Check the sublime console, there might be a message explaining the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure this out. So I just switched to HTML-CSS-JS prettify sublime module. It does a good job of prettifying all three files. It also allow multiple different settings in the 'Package Settings' where you can configure how you want your prettifier to behave.

Hope this helps someone looking for solution to a similar problem.